# Console application using the YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube

I'm about to build a console application that needs access to the authenticated YouTube Data API. Calling the API's themselves is not a problem, I know quite well how to make and process HTTPS requests.

I've already gotten the API key and the Client ID. No problems there, either.

The problem is the authentication.
I've checked here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#installed-apps
On the "Installed applications" tab, in step two, it instructs on how to set up a url to call to do the authentication step. All good so far. But before programming anything, I thought I'd try and see what that url does in the browser.

Turns out it just displays a login prompt. Well how about that. That won't work in this kind of console application. The idea is, presumably, that the user is somehow shown this webpage and be instructed to login and allow access. Then, somehow, by some kind of magic perhaps, the access token is sent back to my console application.

Two things I'm not quite sure about:
1) How do I prompt for the username and/or password in the console app and send *that* to the authentication URL?
2) How would I get the access token back from it?

The biggest problem is that the API seems to require a browser... Which isn't there. My console application will (eventually) run unattended, so starting up a browser and displaying a webpage and doing nothing until it returns a code, is out of the question. I need to somehow supply the authentication page a username/password and get back the code right away.